# how to test void methods at junit in order to increase code coverage

Tags: testing, junit, code-coverage

I want to increase code coverage in junit testing . I have too many methods and all these methods are nearly in the type of "void". Therefore, I could not make assertian or any other junit tests in the void methods. I heard in the forums to test a variable in the void method to increase code coverage. But still it does not work ? What do i need to do to increase code coverage at Junit ?

For instance, in the following code I want to test transform method, not createAngularMethod. How I can do that ?

Regards
Alper

```
public void transform(File fileToTransform, LogGenerator logGenerator) {
        createAngularLines(menu, transform);
   }

 private StringBuilder createAngularLines(Menu menu, Transform transform) {

    StringBuilder angularLines = createInitialAngularLines(transform);
    createBodyOfTheAngularPage(angularLines, transform);
    createNextMethod(angularLines,transform);
    createAngularLines(menu);
    return angularLines;
}
```

Comment: We want sample code.

Comment: provide the code which you are trying to test

Comment: The transform method doesn't do anything, it just calls createAngularLines. What do you want to test here? I really don't like writing test cases just for the sake of code coverage. You have a higher percentage, that's the _only_ benefit you gain here, the disadvantage is, you have a test case which tests virtually nothing, doesn't help at all and will someday confuse someone.

Comment: well I want to test all the method. The question is very clear. If you know a way how to test void method to increase code coverage, pls let me know if not then you can tell me YOU CANNOT. there is no need to find fancy words.Regards